# How to export obj line elements from edges?

Tags: edges, obj

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file#Line_elements), Line elements can exist in `.obj` files.

> l v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 ...

I have an existing mesh in Blender and I would like to re-export it as an .obj such that it also contains the line elements section based on the edges I have selected in Blender.

[image]

Comment: The fact that the OBJ standard supports lines doesn't mean the Blender exporter can actually write them, and as far as I know it doesn't. Also if it does it is probably not be based on transitory geometry selections, you'd most likely have to have a separate geometry for that.